# Collection with prevent duplicate record and sort

Tags: java, list, collections, set, treeset

As my understand, `Set` can help to prevent duplicate record, but it can not be sort.

If use `List`, then it can be sort, but I cant prevent duplicate record.

If I use `TreeSet`, then the object in my `TreeSet` must implements `Comparable`, which is need big changes in my project, and if possible, I not prefer to change this.

Maybe I can convert the `Set` to `List`, and then sort it. However, my program follow is a bit complicated, means after I sort it, I still need to add in object inside this `list`, and at the same time, I would like to prevent duplicate, so, to do this, I have to convert the sorted `List` to `Set` again, and then only add in new object inside.

I would like to seek for an approach which can make my collection sorted according to object value and prevent duplicate record at the same time.

Hopefully I am not asking wrong things on this.

Comment: How would you sort your list?

Comment: @shmosel, I would like to sort it base on the value in my object. For example, the object call payment, then I will sort by the paymentId, or sort by reference number, for example.

Comment: But *how*? What I'm getting at is, whatever you use to sort the list, you should be able to use for a TreeSet.

Comment: @shmosel , At first I am not passing the Comparable to my `TreeSet` object, so I thought TreeSet object must implement Comparable at first. But now I pass a Comparator to my TreeSet and solved my problem. : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TreeSet` seems the best fit for your requirements.

> If I use TreeSet, then the object in my TreeSet must implements Comparable

That's not true. `TreeSet` doesn't require your element type to implement `Comparable`. You can pass a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` constructor instead.

Since your element type doesn't implement `Comparable`, you would have needed a `Comparator` anyway if you were going to sort a `List`, so instead of sorting a `List`, use that `Comparator` with a `TreeSet`.